# How do I set a predicate for a Route.Builder in Spring Cloud Gateway?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

I won't go into much detail (it's not hugely relevant, and it's a lot of code), but here's an interface I wrote:

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface RouteProcessor {
    // DocumentedEndpoint is my custom class that encapsulates an exposed endpoint of a service
    Route.Builder process(Route.Builder routeInConstruction, DocumentedEndpoint endpoint);
}
```

It's used like this (it's a basic idea, not final code):

```java
    private void buildAndAddRoutesFrom(List<? extends DocumentedEndpoint> endpoints) {
        for (DocumentedEndpoint endpoint : endpoints) {
            Route.Builder routeBuilder = Route.builder();
            for (RouteProcessor routeProcessor : routeProcessors) {
                routeBuilder = routeProcessor.process(routeBuilder, endpoint);
            }
            routeFlux = routeFlux.concatWith(Mono.just(routeBuilder.build())); // questionable, but it's beyond the point for now
        }
    }
```

Again, it's not really important. What's important is that Spring Cloud Gateway's sources have, to put it mildly, room for improvement (in my view). In particular, I don't know how I do such a simple thing as adding a predicate to a `Route` in construction. Like, suppose I construct it. Where do I pass it now?

```java
    @Bean
    public RouteProcessor authenticationRouteProcessor() {
        return (routeInConstruction, endpoint) -> {
                AsyncPredicate<ServerWebExchange> newPredicate = AsyncPredicate.from(serverWebExchange -> serverWebExchange
                        .getRequest()
                        .getPath()
                        .toString()
                        .startsWith("/api/v1"));

                AsyncPredicate<ServerWebExchange> compoundPredicate = routeInConstruction.getPredicate().and(predicate);

                // what's next?
```

How do I set a predicate for a `Route.Builder` in Spring Cloud Gateway?

Like, if you're saying that it's the only way I can pass it, by invoking this constructor (which is private, btw):

```java
// from Route.AbstractBuilder

        public Route build() {
            Assert.notNull(this.id, "id can not be null");
            Assert.notNull(this.uri, "uri can not be null");
            AsyncPredicate<ServerWebExchange> predicate = getPredicate();
            Assert.notNull(predicate, "predicate can not be null");

            // Route has predicate, but Route.Builder doesn't!
            return new Route(this.id, this.uri, this.order, predicate, this.gatewayFilters, this.metadata);
        }
```

Gateway's design surprises me

I mean we have this nice `and()` method that we can use as a setter

```java
        public Builder and(Predicate<ServerWebExchange> predicate) {
            Assert.notNull(this.predicate, "can not call and() on null predicate");
            this.predicate = this.predicate.and(predicate);
            return this;
        }
```

but that setting is basically the method's side effect so it feels more like a workaround rather than something that I should actually do as the library's user

But more importantly, how exactly do I add a predicate to an existing one? It should already be initialized due to the null assert. So this won't work:

```java
        @Bean
    public RouteProcessor basicPredicateProcessor() {
        return (routeInConstruction, endpoint) -> {
            routeInConstruction.and(serverWebExchange -> serverWebExchange
                    .getRequest()
                    .getPath()
                    .toString()
                    .startsWith("/api/v1"));
            return routeInConstruction;
        };
    }
```

Please let me know that it's not that far gone and I missed some crucial snippets of the source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like, before they start to write good code, here's your best bet:

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface RouteProcessor {
    Route.AsyncBuilder process(Route.AsyncBuilder routeInConstruction, DocumentedEndpoint endpoint);
}
```

```java
    private void buildAndAddRoutesFrom(List<? extends DocumentedEndpoint> endpoints) {
        for (DocumentedEndpoint endpoint : endpoints) {
            Route.AsyncBuilder routeBuilder = Route.async();
            for (RouteProcessor routeProcessor : routeProcessors) {
                routeBuilder = routeProcessor.process(routeBuilder, endpoint);
            }
            routeFlux = routeFlux.concatWith(Mono.just(routeBuilder.build()));
        }
    }
```

```java
    @Bean
    // probably you'd want to set it first thing
    // @Order(value = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public RouteProcessor basicPredicateProcessor() {
        return (routeInConstruction, endpoint) -> {
            routeInConstruction.asyncPredicate(AsyncPredicate.from(serverWebExchange -> serverWebExchange
                            .getRequest()
                            .getPath()
                            .toString()
                            .startsWith("/api/v1")
                    ));
            return routeInConstruction;
        };
    }
```

It's because `Route.AsyncBuilder` has a method that doesn't include that null check so you can safely initialize `predicate`:

```java
        public AsyncBuilder asyncPredicate(AsyncPredicate<ServerWebExchange> predicate) {
            this.predicate = predicate;
            return this;
        }
```